# How to get locale selected in keycloak login page, not user default locale?

Tags: java, internationalization, keycloak

I am working on a springboot application with the keycloak springboot adaptor. In the AccessToken, I can find the locale defined in the user keycloak. But i want to get the locale selected on the login page.

How can get this info?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In my application (@ **Server A**) the `/backoffice` urls secured by Keycloak. If a user will open the backoffice he is redirected to Keycloak login (@ **Server B**).

If I pass `ui_locales=de` or `ui_locales=en` in my application on **Server A** then it's respected during the redirect and Keycloak will display the login page in the proper language on **Server B**.

Beforehand, de and en **message properties files a present in your Keycloak themes and internationalization must enabled** in your Keycloak realm configuration.

`localhost:5050/backoffice?ui_locales=de` result in german Keycloak login page and `localhost:5050/backoffice?ui_locales=en` results in english Keycloak login page.

**greetz**

*My sources and thanks to:*

- https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-dev/2018-April/010714.html
- https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest